# How to get int from IndexPath

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I would like to calculate the int value of a IndexPath that has rows and sections to then use to select a object from a NSArray using ObjectAtIndex.

I only have a string value from the UITable so I am trying to relate the indexpath value selected to the ObjectAtIndex path of my actual array.

This is my code so far, but I am getting an error because I am trying to use indexPath in place of a int.

```
filterDataArray = [dataArrayOfDictionaries objectAtIndex:indexPath];
```

so my question is how can i change indexPath Into an int. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The reference docs show you the `UITableView` category for `NSIndexPath`. A quick scan of those docs will reveal the `row` and `section` properties.

Comment: BTW - you don't want an `int`. That is not the type for the `index` parameter to `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: I want to calculate objectAtIndex for a NSArray using indexpath that has sections and rows.

Comment: Then you need to tell us how your data is laid out. Do you have an array with an object for each section. And each of those contains data for the rows for the section?

Comment: no unfortunately not.. I am going to have to think of how else I can do this.

Comment: Please post the data in your array, how it is organized ? How did you showing that to UITableView. Also post the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 2):

so in your case you can use combination of both the row and section values try like this,

```
int totalRows = indexPath.row; //current section row value


for (int n = 0; n < indexPath.section; n++) {//here current section value.

    totalRows += [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:n];// here add rows in every section
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) for better understanding about NSIndexPath.

If you are using NSArray and table view with only one section (one is by default if you do not specify numberOfSections: method). Try this.

```
filterDataArray = [dataArrayOfDictionaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: This dose not work, because I have a table view with sections... so its not relating the correctly selected indexpath with object of the array.

Comment: Hi dude for supporting UITableView with sections you got to have a Array and a Dictionary actually that is the best way to do it.